# Babel dependency not resolved in react app created using "create-react-app" utility

Tags: html, reactjs, babeljs

I have created a react-app using `create-react-app` utility but when I import a node module then it gives me error stating :

```
./node_modules/@nross/react-vega/src/VegaLite.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   onParseError,
|   children,
|   ...otherProps
| }) => {
|   const adjustedSpec = { ...spec };
```

And when I import `babel-loader` into the file where I am importing the node module then it is giving me the error:-

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/babel-core/lib/helpers/resolve.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\VegaDemo\my-app\node_modules\babel-core\lib\helpers'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to eject in order to customize the boilerplate.

Simply run

```
npm run eject
```

Or

```
yarn run eject
```

If you use yarn.

Then, install your npm module and run

```
npm run install
```

Without eject, the boilerplate is locked up.